# I want to get pivot result based on my two tables

Tags: mysql, left-join, sql-query-store

Example Data:

Table: user_field_mapping

| user_id | field_id | field_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | a |
| 1 | 12 | b |
| 1 | 13 | c |
| 2 | 11 | x |
| 2 | 12 | y |

Table: field_master

| field_id | field_name |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | fieldnamefor11 |
| 12 | fieldnamefor12 |
| 13 | fieldnamefor13 |

Required Result

| user_id | fieldnamefor11 | fieldnamefor12 | fieldnamefor13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | c |
| 2 | x | y | null |

this is what I tried...

```
SELECT d.user_id
     , d.value "fieldnamefor11" 
  FROM user_field_mapping d 
  LEFT 
  JOIN field_master f1 
    ON f1.fieldid=d.field_id 
   AND f1.name = 'fieldnamefor11' 
  LEFT 
  JOIN field_master f2 
    ON f2.id=d.field_id 
   AND f2.name = 'fieldnamefor12' 
 order 
    by user_id
     , field_id
```

Comment: Please show your tired code.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code. And see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT UFM.user_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN UFM.field_id = 11 THEN UFM.field_value end) as fieldnamefor11,
       MAX(CASE WHEN UFM.field_id = 12 THEN UFM.field_value end) as fieldnamefor12,
       MAX(CASE WHEN UFM.field_id = 13 THEN UFM.field_value end ) as fieldnamefor13
  FROM user_field_mapping  UFM inner join
       field_master  FM ON UFM.field_id = FM.field_id
  Group by UFM.user_id
```

and the result;

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the desired result using conditional aggregation -

```
SELECT UFM.user_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 11 THEN UFM.field_value END) fieldnamefor11,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 12 THEN UFM.field_value END) fieldnamefor12,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 13 THEN UFM.field_value END) fieldnamefor13
  FROM user_field_mapping UFM
  JOIN field_master FM ON UFM.field_id = FM.field_id
 GROUP BY UFM.user_id;
```